# Hiding a namespace from internal mediawiki search?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

Does anyone know of a way to hide a namespace or category from the internal search results of a mediawiki site?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that via the [$wgNamespacesToBeSearchedDefault](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:%24wgNamespacesToBeSearchedDefault) variable.

Seems you would need to list there all the namespaces you **yes** want to be searchable, instead of listing the the small handful you don't want to be searchable.

Comment: Thanks for the info! So the only way to do it would be to add in all the namespaces I want searchable instead of some way to ignore the small handful I dont want searchable?

Comment: Note that this only determines the default search settings. Users can always go to Special:Search (or their preferences if they are logged in) and override it.